# How to deploy a second Load Balancer for istio 1.5.1 on Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-load-balancer

I would need to deploy a second Azure Load Balancer for ingress gateway of an app (to be separated from the main Load Balancer deployed in the istio's default profile).

I have tried the suggestions on GitHub (https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19263). However, the result was actually an additonal Frontend IP Configuration for the main Load Balancer, and not an additional Load Balancer. This ends up with "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" error (if curl is used: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number), if the same port 443 is used in both istio ingress gateways.

istio version: 1.5.1

Any suggestions on how to deploy an additional Load Balancer for the second ingress gateway? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky configuration as it needs to have an entire new second istio ingress gateway (not just a gateway object). There is an article about this [here](https://www.learncloudnative.com/blog/2020-01-09-deploying_multiple_gateways_with_istio/).

This approach creates new `HorizontalPodAutoscaler`, `Deployment`, `Gateway`, `PodDisruptionBudget`, `Service`, `ServiceAccount` for the second istio ingress gateway based on the default configuration.

After modifying all the names labels You can `kubectl apply` the manifest to Your istio cluster . As for the Loadbalancer, new one will be attached to new istio-ingress gateway automatically.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot test your suggestion (https://www.learncloudnative.com/blog/2020-01-09-deploying_multiple_gateways_with_istio/) right now. I accept the answer.